# Copy range of data without 0 or empty cells with a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to copy a range of data without 0 or empty cells.

Then I use this formula in the targeted sheet in the cell `A2` (`A1` is the header).

```
=OFFSET(DataSheet!$A$2;0;0;COUNTA(DataSheet!$A:$A);1)
```

Result is

```
  A  |
------
 Id  |
100  |
150  |
147  |
1258 |
7895 |
68   |
1231 |
0    |
```

It is possible to get the same result without the 0 at the end ?

```
  A  |
------
 Id  |
100  |
150  |
147  |
1258 |
7895 |
68   |
1231 |
```

Thank you in advance !

Regards,

Comment: You to use `IF(...` formula or `FILTER()` formula with offset.

Comment: I tried to use `=FILTER(OFFSET(DataSheet!$A$2;0;0;COUNTA(DataSheet!$A:$A);1);DataSheet!$A:$A<>"")` however it is returning `#VALUE!`. I dont understand why ...

Comment: Without sample data I can not test but you can give a try `=LET(x;OFFSET(DataSheet!$A$2;0;0;COUNTA(DataSheet!$A:$A);1);FILTER(x;x>0))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this works just fine in office 365

```
=FILTER(A:A,A:A>0)
```

it ignores zeroes and blanks

Comment: Oh thank you. And is it possible to exclude `#N/A` with `FILTER` function also?

Comment: =FILTER(IFERROR(A:A,0),IFERROR(A:A,0)>0)